# Speed up downloading file through HttpUrlConnection. Android

Tags: android, file, httpurlconnection

I have application for Android, that downloading files from remote server. And my app downloading files much more slowly as ios application the same file at the same Internet connection. 
That my code:

```
            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream    
            FileOutputStream output =
                    context.openFileOutput(new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName).getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(String.valueOf((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile)));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

What can help in solving this problem.

Comment: @MKJParekh The matter is that i downloading audio and video files, not images. And libraries as Picasso, Universal Image Loader and other here can not use.

Comment: I use Retrofit library for communication with server. Is Retrofit can downloading files faster?

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. Those libraries are not for this. Please ignore